# custom 404 error page in django 1.5

Tags: django

I was trying to develop a custom 404 error page in my django website. I implemented everything as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497471/django-tutorial-custom-404-and-500-views). But then a problem occurred when I tried it with an invalid url.

`TemplateDoesNotExist: 500-page.html`

`handler500 = 'polls.views.error500'` instead of `mysite.views.error500` why it is not recognising my template.
As per the link I placed the 500-page html on the root templates folder.

#### My error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/anuj/Envs/estoppeleasy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/anuj/Envs/estoppeleasy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 156, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/anuj/Envs/estoppeleasy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 224, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/home/anuj/Envs/estoppeleasy/letterproject/estoppeleasy/web/views.py", line 68, in error500
    return render(request,'500-page.html')
  File "/home/anuj/Envs/estoppeleasy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 53, in render
    return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
  File "/home/anuj/Envs/estoppeleasy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 170, in render_to_string
    t = get_template(template_name)
  File "/home/anuj/Envs/estoppeleasy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 146, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)
  File "/home/anuj/Envs/estoppeleasy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 139, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: 500-page.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You template should be named `500.html` and `404.html` not `500-page.html`. You don't need any extra views for this. It all works out of the box. Remove all extra stuff you may have added to your `urls.py`, `settings.py` or `views.py` regarding to the 500 error.

Just and only put a `500.html` file into your templates-root folder.
Keep in mind to NOT extend your `base.html`. Create a fresh clean self-running html file without any includes or extends.

Comment: Why not extend `base.html`? I think I did it and it worked. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Mostly you use template tags and stuff in your base. If you're running in a 500 crash usually there is some problem with a middleware, context processor and so on - so loading the base with all that stuff is another error crashing your 500 page. You may use it for 404 - but I do not recommend it for 500.

Answer (score 0):

Create templates named `500.html` and `404.html` and place in `root folder of template directory` and it will work.