# Raising Exceptions in Django REST

Tags: django

I'm trying to test the exceptions within the django rest framework.
Based on http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/ raising NotFound,

> By default this exception results in a response with the HTTP status
>   code "404 Not Found".

However when I issue a GET (to /example1) I get a 500 with ,

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.59.103:8002/example1
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: NotFound
Exception Value:    
not found
Exception Location: /home/djangoapp/testtools/api/views.py in example1, line 7
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
```

details below,

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {'EXCEPTION_HANDLER':'rest_framework.views.exception_handler'}

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from api import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'example1', views.example1),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException,ParseError,NotFound

def example1(request):                                                                                                                               
    raise NotFound("not found")
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: In your comments to @ArpitGoyal's answer you say you actually want to know how to generate your own 404 response for any URL not just this sample code.  can you please clarify the question if that's true?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound
```

The class `NotFound` is extended from `APIException`. The default status code for `APIException` is `500 Internal Server Error`, whereas for `NotFound` is `404`.

So according to me here you are trying to throw a `rest framework` exception in a pure django view. I wrote a test case here to check what are the odds of getting the error raised. Guess what a simple django view trying to raise a `rest framework` exception is not recognized as an error to the view. But on providing the decorator and declaring it an API View it enters the `exception_handler`

So when you do:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view()
def example1(request):
    raise NotFound('not found')
```

This is now recognized as an exception thrown by the API which enters the default `rest_framework` `EXCEPTION_HANDLER` provided by you, where it returns the response for any given exception.

Its `docstring` says:

> Returns the response that should be used for any given exception. By
>   default we handle the REST framework `APIException`, and also Django's
>   built-in `ValidationError`, `Http404` and `PermissionDenied`
>   exceptions.    Any unhandled exceptions may return `None`, which will
>   cause a 500 error to be raised.

Comment: Ok cool. Makes sense. Also If i then throw a request for /example2 should this not raise the NotFound by the DRF without the need for me to configure anything else.

Comment: The behaviour should be same for every url if the code remains the same.

Comment: ok, i must be missing something as cant get it to auto generate the 404 JSON response

Comment: Any ideas. your answer answers 90% of the question its just the last bit.

Comment: I didn't get you. The only thing here I can think off is that only. The NotFound is an api exception and you can raise it as an error only on an APIView. In a pure django view it is recognised as an internal server error. What did you mean with the last part?

Comment: I may be confused, but in short I just want NotFound to be raised returned when a url not in urls.py without the need of setting it myself in the views

Comment: How will your error being raised if the url is not found in urls.py, it will not enter the view if there is no url for it and hence you cannot raise any error. That django will throw if you have no urls specified in urls.py.

Comment: However you can define the custom 404 and 500 handler, check out the following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497471/django-tutorial-custom-404-and-500-views

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are doing this. That's an internal exception used by DRF when it can't find a resource. But you're using it in a standard Django view, outside any of the DRF machinery. If you want to do that, you should use the standard Django exception:

```
from django.core.exceptions import Http404

def example1(request):
    raise Http404('not found')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your url with a reqular expression which matches all possible urls and place it at the end of the main urls.py

for ex:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/', views.example1),
]
```